# Java making a method that does the same thing as str.indexOf() from the java.lang.string class

Tags: java, indexof, charat

just as an exercise I am trying to make a method that takes a string and a char as user input and finds whether or not that string contains the char. If it does it will return the index found if not it will return -1.

I'm pretty stumped on how to do this without using an array but here is what I am trying to do:

```
      StringIndexOfChar.indexOf(String str, char ch) {

       for (int i=0; i <= str.length(); i++) {
       str.charAt(i);

       if (ch == str.charAt(i)) {
       return i; }}

       return -1; }
```

Comment: Read the javadoc of String. It contains the information you're looking for, i.e. how to get the length of a string.

Comment: In your code you don't define str or char or i.  Also don't name a variable the same as a type name, name the variable based on what it is used for.

Comment: Also the real indexOf returns the index i on success, or -1 on failure.  Otherwise you would be returning a char in one case and an int in the other.

Comment: thanks I've got it up and running now, turns out I wanted the index not the char all along

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should look something like this:

```
//method declarations need to declare the return type, name, and arguments
int indexOf(String s, char ch) {

 //loop over each index in the string
 for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

  //if the char at this index is the one we are looking for
  if (ch == s.charAt(i)) {

   //return the index it was found it
   return i;
  }
 }

 //if we look at each char and do not find the one we want, return -1
 return -1;
}
```

If you have questions about how it works please ask and I will gladly answer.

Comment: should it be i <= s.length()?

Comment: @James If it helped you please upvote and mark it as an answer to counteract these people randomly downvoting for no reason.

Comment: his question is a bit vague "If it does it will return the char if not it will return -1.", probably the index by what he meant

Comment: alright, upvoted. I don't see anyway to add it as an answer though?

Comment: @James--click the big gray arrow to the left of the Answer pane. When it turns green, you've selected your Answer.

Comment: @James thanks, I appreciate it. I don't know why people downvote for trying to help someone who is new to programming. The least they could do is explain their downvote.

Comment: no sweat! I don't know man, maybe because it was a trivial question or my wording was off. I don't really know the terminology yet